# Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in file

Tags: laravel, eloquent

gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Tengo una consulta SQL, raw. en laravel que me regresa un registro con varios campos, y no he podido acceder a unos de los campos que me regresa.
Como puedo hacer esto?

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM pedido
               WHERE codcli=$id
            and (sucursal= 'una' or sucursal= 'dos')
            order BY id_nombre desc 
            limit 1";
        


$data = DB::select($sql);
```

me regresa registros (Especificamente uno), hasta ahí, todo funciona ok.

pero luego quiero obtener el valor de uno de los datos que me regresa, pero no he podido.

```
$id = $data[0]['id_nombre']; //Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in file 
$id = $data->id_nombre;  // ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id_nombre' of non-object in file
$id = $data['id_nombre'];  // ErrorException: Undefined index: id_nombre in file
```

Que podria hacer? muchas gracias.

Cuando hago un dd a data me muestra:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#349 ▼
    +"id_nombre": 1234
    +"id_orden": "1234"
    +"sucursal": "una"
  }
]
```

cuando hago un return:

```
[{"id_nombre":1234,"id_orden":"1234", "sucursal":"una"}]
```

Comment: Realiza un `dd` de `$data` y muestranos que obtienes

Comment: Este es el return de data:
[{"id_nombre":1498,"id_orden":"1234","fecha":"2021-06-03","codcli":1234, "codusuari":1234,"total":0}]

Comment: Este es un dd:
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#349 ▼
    +"id_nombre": 1498
    +"id_orden": "1234" 
  }
]

Comment: Ya veo, dame un momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está devolviendo un arreglo tu consulta. Solo tienes que hacer `$data[0]->id_nombre;`.

Como consejo, te diría que estás usando mal los beneficios que te otorgan los query builder e incluso los modelos de Laravel.

Tu consulta creo que sería más fácil si sólo hicieras algo como esto:

```
$data = DB::table('pedido')->where('codcli', $id)->where(function($query){
   $query->where('sucursal', 'una')
       ->orWhere('sucursal', 'dos');
})
->orderByDesc('id_nombre')
->first();
```

Esto te devolvería solo un registro y solo deberías hacer `$data->id_nombre;`

Comment: amigo muchas gracias, por tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda. gracias. al final, las dos respuestas que me dieron, tu y @BetaM, me sirvieron mucho, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el método `SELECT` del *facade* **`DB`** te esta devolviendo un solo resultado dentro de una estructura así:

```
[
    {
      ............ (aqui es donde esta tu objeto de valores)
    }
]
```

Es decir tu objeto esta dentro de un array,

Opción 1.

Motivo por el cual por ejemplo tendrías que indicar el índice (0 en este caso) en el cual se encuentra dicho objeto.

Quedando de esta manera:

```
$id = $data[0]->id_nombre;
```

Opción 2.

Iterar por medio de un *foreach* a dicho array y entonces podrás leer y asignar en variables todos los valores recuperados, así:

```
foreach ($data as $dato) {
    echo $dato->id_nombre;
    echo $dato->id_orden;
    ...............
}
```

Opcion 3.

Te facilitas la vida por medio del *query builder* y la escribes del siguiente modo:

```
$consultaPedido = Pedido::where('codcli', $id)
                        ->where(function ($query) {
                            $query->whereIn('sucursal', ['una', 'dos']);
                        })->orderBy('id_nombre', 'DESC')
                        ->first();
```

Al usar **`first`** obtendremos en lugar de una colección solo un objeto y podrás sin problema emplear la sintaxis de:

```
$consultaPedido->clave1;
$consultaPedido->claveN;
```

Por cierto con un `whereIn` solucionas la condición que esta dentro de los paréntesis desde el momento en que solo es necesario alguno de los 2 pero no ambos

**Referencias**

- [Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction)
- [Método whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein)

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu ayuda, he aprendido mucho en toda tu respuesta. te lo agradezco mucho. Me gastè bastante tiempo tratando de hacerlo con wherein, pero al final no pude y me quedè con la opcion de hacerlo "manual" muchas gracias, por tu ayuda.

Comment: Revisa mi edición me faltaba un `;` que ya coloqué @wil